# MVC 5 HTML Code Snippets not working after upgrade of MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, code-snippets

I recently upgraded from MVC 4 to MVC 5. Since that upgrade, my Code Snippets have not been working that I previously created. There are almost no resources online for this (for MVC 5) and any previously tutorial that shows how to create a snippet does not work. I'm using **Visual Studio 2013** (update 1, but update 2 also does not fix it).

Here's my snippet:

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<Header>
    <Title>JSLessBehavior</Title>
    <Author>OptixConnect LLC</Author>
    <Shortcut>jslessBehavior</Shortcut>
    <Description>Markup snippet for a JSLess behavior helper</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>            
    </SnippetTypes>
</Header>

<Snippet>
    <Declarations>
        <Literal>
            <ID>name</ID>
            <ToolTip>name</ToolTip>
            <Default>execute</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>toggle</ID>
            <ToolTip>toggle</ToolTip>
            <Default>toggle</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>target</ID>
            <ToolTip>target</ToolTip>
            <Default>self</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>params</ID>
            <ToolTip>params</ToolTip>
            <Default>params</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="html">
        <![CDATA[data-jsless="@(new object[] { new { name = "$name$", method = "$toggle$", target = "$target$", @params = new object[] { "$params$" } } }.ToJsonObject())"]]>
    </Code>     
</Snippet>
```

The expected outcome would be if I start typing `<div jslessBehavior` and then press tab + tab it should auto generate that snippet. Has something changed when going from MVC 4 to 5?

The default code snippets that Visual Studio provides work. And I tried copying one of their HTML snippets and just refactoring it to use my code with no luck :(

Comment: Same here :(. Did you manage to get these to work? I can't seem to get any snippets working in VS 2013 with Update 2 and MVC5 projects either.

Comment: @SandeepPhadke unforunately I haven't figured it out. I'm still on update 1 (keep forgetting to update to 2). I'm not quite sure where else to turn to ask this question...please keep me posted though if you ever figure it out!

Comment: FYI I created a [feedback bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/888854/custom-html-code-snippets-do-not-seem-to-work-in-vs-2013-update-2-in-mvc-5-projects) in Microsoft connect - can you please add a vote to that?